# asp.net - upload file to a different server

Tags: asp.net, iis, file-upload

I have a web application in a farm with a web server and a file server.  One of the primary features of our web app is the storage of files.

I need to find a way to have a user connect to the website, select the file(s) to upload to the server, and the files are uploaded directly to the file server, not the web server.

Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I came to the conclusion that what I want is not totally possible.  I ended up changing my architecture, and each remote file server has local upload capability.  Perhaps in the future there will be a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you. [Uploading files to file server using webclient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263518/c-uploading-files-to-file-server)

Comment: That is interesting and helpful, and may end up being my solution. Unfortunately, I'm really trying to find a solution which bypasses uploading to the web server and then copying to the fileserver, because it is 2x the traffic...but a upload and then copy system might be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the absolute path ,for more details about this issue check the following link:

[How to upload a file outside the web server.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3467345/418343)